# Too many arguments in call to 'select' error | R | dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

***the error***

[image]

This error only appeared when I finished running through the script. At the start, it worked fine. I did not make changes to that call after it worked. Some columns were added to 'equipment' later after this select call.

Comment: Did you try restarting the R session and rerunning the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have loaded another package in your script which probably has an conflict with select from dplyr try to write `dplyr::select` instead

Comment: Yes. I fixed it by restarting R Studio and reloading all the packages I needed.